# Is JPA Entity Manager is thread local?

Tags: jpa

I read somewhere entity manager is thread local, so does it mean that if thread exits its execution all entities which are in persistent state to this entity manager will again become detached and available for modification if thread of execution completes.

I have a microservice architecture in which each microservice has 30 consumer threads and I am doing both read, write and delete operation, is it necessary to clear the entitymanager ?.

Comment: The `EntityManager` is under *your* control for creation and closure; make it ThreadLocal if you want. What you read does not say what you think it does.

Comment: While what @BillyFrost said is true, a lot depends on your transaction configuration, because transactions *are* thread-local more often than not. This means that regardless of whether the `EntityManager` is thread local or not, it may still be unsafe to use across multiple threads

Comment: Ok, which means the best practice is to close EntityManager after each thread of execution.